# RadGrid Column editable on insert but set to readonly on update

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

I have a RadGrid which has a column like:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Car" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="MakeLabel" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Make") %> />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="MakeTextBox" runat="Server" Text='<%# Bind("Make") %> />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn >
```

and I'm wanting to set it up so that this column will allow input when inserting new values but won't when updating values.

Can someone please make a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way for you to accomplish this would be by adding an InsertItemTemplate and changing the EditItemTemplate to a Label.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Car" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="MakeLabel" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Make") %> />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="MakeTextBox" runat="Server" Text='<%# Bind("Make") %> />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="MakeLabel" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Make") %> />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn >
```

This way, you don't have to mess around with it in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question when searching for a solution to this myself.  I was able to cobble something together that works; don't know if it's the best way, but I tend to go with what works.  ;-)

Set your `GridTemplateColumn` as `ReadOnly="true"`, and be sure to give it a `UniqueName` property.  Then create a PreRender handler for the grid that does this:

```
    Private Sub RadGrid1_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.PreRender
        For Each column As GridColumn In RadGrid.Columns
            If column.UniqueName = "MyName" Then
                If column.Owner.IsItemInserted Then
                    CType(column, GridTemplateColumn).ReadOnly = False 
                Else
                    CType(column, GridTemplateColumn).ReadOnly = True
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        RadGrid1.Rebind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I made an edit to include an "Else" clause to set the ReadOnly property to "True".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with in the Page_Load

```
myTextBox.Enabled = Parent.NamingContainer is GridEditFormInsertItem;
```

This is in the usercontrol used for updates/inserts of data